# Generate terrain from heightmap array

Tags: modifiers

I have an array of z coordinates and I want to generate a terrain. I don't understand how to do it.

[image]

In java it was simple:

```
float[] heightmap = new float[2048];
TerrainQuad terrain = new TerrainQuad("terrain", 65, 2049, heightmap);
```

But in Blender I can't do it.

While i was experimenting generate meshes in blender api, blender crashed several times, and i don't have the code to show my attempts. Just that...
[image]

Comment: Have you tried going into edit mode ? You're creating a single face between 4 vertices that have random coordinates, of course it will create something horrible. Try using triangles only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### [image: AI Icon] Warning, Potential AI generated content⚠️
>
> **This post is suspected to have been generated with the help of an artificial intelligence, chat bot, or other language model tools without proper attribution.**
>
> There is reason to believe this post was not written by a human due to its structure, and grammatical construction, and has been marked by our community.
> Current AI chat bots are a language models, that means they are like a parrot, they can mimic human language well, but they are built to write **seemingly** logical, **seemingly** factual grammatically valid text, rather than actually **be correct**, like a human would.
> The veracity of the following content cannot be ascertained.
> See the [Concerns regarding AI generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396).

ChatGPT generated a code for me and it works. Instead of a random Z value array, I put a heightmap, and the correct value of the size.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

# create a 2D z array
size = 10
z_array = np.random.rand(size, size)

# create a new mesh
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('MyMesh')

# define vertices from z array
verts = []
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        z_value = z_array[i][j]
        verts.append((i, j, z_value))

# define faces
faces = []
for i in range(size-1):
    for j in range(size-1):
        a = i * size + j
        b = i * size + (j+1)
        c = (i+1) * size + j
        d = (i+1) * size + (j+1)
        faces.append((a, b, d, c))

# create the mesh object
mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)

# create a new object and link it to the scene
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('MyObject', mesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
```